# N Channel MOSFET for reverse polarity protection for circuit with two possible voltage sources

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design

I am designing a circuit board that has two possible ways to receive 20V DC power, either from USB power delivery, or from a screw terminal.

When the board is powered via USB power delivery (`USB_PD_20V`), I would like the screw terminal to act as an output for the 20V.

However, when the power input is from the screw terminal, I would like to prevent any reverse current/polarity on `USB_PD_20V` (Note: `USB_PD_20V` will be at 0V when inactive).

1. Is the schematic below suitable?
2. Is the resistor pointless?

(I am using the Zener diode to prevent V<sub>GS(max)</sub> from being exceeded)
[image: Schematic]

Thank you!

Edit:
Attempt 2:
[image: Attempt 2]

Comment: The schematic has to be wrong because the MOSFET can never become activated.

Comment: Oh dear yes i mixed up the source and drain

Comment: No, that is not the problem, @kekpirat: The gate is just a (rather small) capacitor. There's no DC flowing through it. So, no current flows through R50. With 0 current, there's zero voltage across R50. The same is true for D18 (yes, even if it's a Zener diode). So, \$U_{GS} \equiv 0\$ under any circumstance. So, that is *always* sub-threshold. So, that MOSFET *can* **never** be active. If there's current flowing through it, it's because you operate it with current flowing from Source to Drain through the body diode, not because you turned it on. And if you now swap D and S, you just built a …

Comment: diode that is in the exact opposite direction of what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your circuit doesn't do what you think it does.

As discussed in the comments, because there's no DC current flowing through a MOSFET gate, there's no voltage drop across D18 and R50, and your U<sub>GS</sub>=0, and your NMOS is never active. It doesn't matter which side is powered.

Anyways, you don't need a MOSFET here at all; currents from USB PD won't be *huge*, so simply use a diode instead of your three-component MOSFET approach. Schottky diodes rated for 10 A to 60 A will commonly have forward voltages below 350 mV,  which would amount to manageable losses within the current maximum of 5A (that I remember for USB-PD at 20 V).

If these 1.75 W of loss seem too high, you can of course still build an "closer to ideal diode-equivalent" using a MOSFET; but for your high-side switching needs, that would need to be a PMOS, as far as I can tell, and some logic that compares USB PD to clamp voltage.

Comment: I don't know if you meant it this way but, when the right side is powered, current will still flow into the `USB PD in` port if something is connected because the MOSFET will still be activated from the right-side. That circuit only provides reverse (negative) voltage protection.

Comment: I think what might be needed is a voltage comparator and, if right voltage is a few millivolts (or more) above left voltage then it shuts down the MOSFET. It doesn't prevent possibly a few tens of mA passing the wrong way but, it might be enough.

Comment: Ah right, I was so focused on the "what if the voltage on in is below the voltage on out" that I didn't realize I reconstructed something from memory that does something else. D'oh. Let me remove that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for a non-diode solution as I would like to minimise power usage in my battery-powered device. I have updated my question with a 2nd attempt which I'm thinking about

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in existing posts. Ask them in new posts. It's also not clear why you think this would use less power than a Schottky diode (hint: it won't, I'm not sure why this should work at al.) Have you tried simulating any of your circuits?

Comment: You're still trying to use N-channel MOSFET high-side switches. That is, unless you have a gate driver that can reliably source a higher voltage, simply not work, because your G needs to be one threshold voltage higher than your S, and that's not the case while the device is operating. If your attempts continue to be centered around NMOS, I don't see how they'll work with much much more advanced circuitry around them.

Answer (score 2):

> *Edit: Attempt 2:*

The 2nd attempt will also not do anything useful.

It's really not as easy as you think. You have to detect that the right side voltage is greater than the left side voltage (and deactivate the MOSFET) and, you have to use a P-channel MOSFET.

If the left side voltage is greater, current will flow how you want it to. If the right side voltage is greater, you must deactivate the p-channel MOSFET.